# Rendering data with HTML from Dato to Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I'm using datocms as a headless CMS and bringing that data into gatsby. I am using a field which in dato which outputs HTML. You can see the graphQL query result here.

```
{
 "data": {
"datoCmsHomepage": {
  "mainTextNode": {
    "id": "DatoCmsHomepage-207812-enMainTextTextNode",
    "mainText": "<p>Some text here.</p>"
  },
  "mainText": "<p>Some text here.</p>" <-- THIS IS MY ISSUE LINE
 }
}
}
```

But when I bring this into gatsby the page is rendering the paragraph tag on the page

here is my code

```
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => (

<div>
 <Jumbotron fluid className="sydbg text-right text-light">
    <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 7, offset: 5 }}>
        <h1 className="display-3">{data.datoCmsHomepage.mainHeading}</h1>
        <p className="lead">{data.datoCmsHomepage.introText}</p>
        <hr className="my-2" />        
        <p >
          <Button color="danger">Book now</Button>
        </p>
        </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container> 
 </Jumbotron>

 <Container className="text-center">
  <Row>
    <Col>
      <h2>{data.datoCmsHomepage.subHeading}</h2>
      {data.datoCmsHomepage.mainText}
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>

</div>

)

export default IndexPage

export const query = graphql`
  query IndexPageQuery {
    datoCmsHomepage {
      mainHeading
      introText
      subHeading
      mainText

    }
  }
`
```

Is this a bug with gatby or am i missing somehting in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean the page is **not** rendering the paragraph? If not then I'm not quite sure what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

All good i figured it out.

{data.datoCmsHomepage.mainText} need to be placed inside the snippet below...

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.datoCmsHomepage.mainText }} />
```